# Enabling GPS in Microsoft Band Tile?

Tags: microsoft-band

After reading numerous questions regarding the inability to stream GPS data from the band I'm wondering whether or not GPS can simply be enabled through a third party app.  My goal is to create a run tracking app, very similar to the stock one, but this one will provide haptic feedback when it's time to start and stop a prescribed interval.  Very similar to Guided Workouts, but with GPS enabled.  I don't want to stream the GPS data, just simply turn it on, store it to the band, and then let it sync up once I'm back with my phone.  I don't run with my phone, just my band and a pair of shorts. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Band SDK does not expose a means to accumulate and then retrieve sensor data from the Band.  An application using the SDK can only stream sensor data in real-time.

Comment: Do you know if MSFT plans on updating the SDK to allow for the creation of stand alone apps?

Comment: The Band runs only its own custom firmware; it does not have an "application model" that would otherwise allow 3rd-party applications to be downloaded and run.  I cannot speak to the product team's plans, however.  You can vote for such a feature on User Voice: https://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band